# Is preimage of closure equal to closure of preimage under continuous topological maps?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map of topological spaces and $B \subseteq Y$

---

Is it true that $f^{-1}(\overline{B})=\overline{f^{-1}(B)}$?

Comment: This has been answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1512632/55622).

Comment: To be clear: the answer is no, and the thread to which Oliver Jones links provides a counter-example: if $X$ and $Y$ are the same set, $X$ has the discrete topology, and $Y$ has any other topology, $f$ is the identity function, and $B$ is some set which is not closed in $Y$, then evidently equality does not hold, since $B$ is closed in $X$, but $\overline B \ne B$ in $Y$.

Comment: And this is true when $f$ is an open map.