# Prove continuity from preservation of sequential limits but do not use $f(\bar{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Munkres Topology:

> **Theorem 21.3.** Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$. If the function $f$ is continuous, then for every convergent sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $X$, the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. The converse holds if $X$ is metrizable.

I understand the first statement. My question is about the converse assuming that $X$ is metrizable. Munkres does this by proving the equivalent formulation of continuity $f(\bar{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}, A \subseteq X$. How do I prove that $f$ directly satisfies the original definition of continuity?

> **Definition of continuity**: For each open subset V of Y, the set $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of X.

I can type up my proof later (I have to organize my messy notes), but for now: I was able to show that $f^{-1}(V)$ is a subset of $f^{-1}(V)'$, which I discovered to be something called dense-in-itself which means no isolated points.

I think I can show $f^{-1}(V)$ is open by showing that $f^{-1}(V)' \cap f^{-1}(V^c)'$ is empty because

- $f^{-1}(V^c) = f^{-1}(V)^c$,
- $U$ is open if and only if $Bd(U)=\overline{U} \setminus U$
- showing that $f^{-1}(V)' \cap f^{-1}(V^c)'$ is empty would imply $Bd(U)=\overline{U} \setminus U$ for $U=f^{-1}(V)$ because $f^{-1}(V) \subseteq f^{-1}(V)'$

What is the contradiction if we say that $f^{-1}(V)' \cap f^{-1}(V^c)'$ is not empty? I'm very confused as to what we get from assuming there is some $z \in f^{-1}(V)'$ and $z \in f^{-1}(V^c)'$.

From $z \in f^{-1}(V)'$, I think I was able to show that $(f^{-1}(V)')'=f^{-1}(V)'$, which means that $f^{-1}(V^c)'$ is something I discovered to be called a perfect set, which means closed and dense-in-itself. According to proofwiki.org, the [Union of Set of Dense-in-itself Sets is Dense-in-itself](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Union_of_Set_of_Dense-in-itself_Sets_is_Dense-in-itself). This means $f^{-1}(V) \cup f^{-1}(V)'$ is dense-in-itself, but $f^{-1}(V) \cup f^{-1}(V)' = \overline{f^{-1}(V)}$, the closure of $f^{-1}(V)$ which is closed. Therefore, $\overline{f^{-1}(V)}$ is perfect.

- Is this related? [Does continuity of $f$ imply $f^{-1}(\bar A)\subset\overline{f^{-1}(A)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881730/does-continuity-of-f-imply-f-1-bar-a-subset-overlinef-1a?rq=1)

I do not know how to proceed from $z \in f^{-1}(V^c)'$. I think this somehow contradicts with $\overline{f^{-1}(V)}$ being perfect.

Also, I showed $f^{-1}(V)$ is infinite if we let $x \in f^{-1}(V)'$ because the [sequence lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931479/does-the-sequence-lemma-hold-for-hausdorff) gives us a sequence $x_n \to x$ where $x_n \in f^{-1}(V)$ . Also, $f(x_n) \in V$ and $f \in \overline{V}$.

However, $f^{-1}(V)$ is infinite, $\overline{f^{-1}(V)}$ is dense-in-itself and $(f^{-1}(V)')' \subseteq f^{-1}(V)'$ can be shown from $T_1$ axiom because according to proofwiki.org again, [Dense-in-itself Subset of T1 Space is Infinite](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dense-in-itself_Subset_of_T1_Space_is_Infinite), [Closure of Dense-in-itself is Dense-in-itself in T1 Space](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closure_of_Dense-in-itself_is_Dense-in-itself_in_T1_Space) and [Derivative of Derivative is Subset of Derivative in T1 Space](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Derivative_is_Subset_of_Derivative_in_T1_Space). Thus, I think there's something else I'm not using. (Of course, I'm not using $f(\bar{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}$ because that's what this question is about.)

Answer (score 1):

The argument should be elementary.

Take $x\in X$ and a sequence $x_n\in X$ with $x_n\to x$. We want to prove that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$, so take an open neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$. By continuity, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open, and it clearly contains $x$. Since $x_n\to x$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\in f^{-1}(V)$ for $n>N$. Then, for $n>N$, it is true that $f(x_n)\in f(f^{-1}(V))\subseteq V$.

We proved: for every open set $V$ with $f(x)\in V$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x_n)\in V$ for $n>N$. This is just the definition of $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

---

Let $X$ be metrizable with metric $d$ and suppose $V$ is an open set of $Y$ with $f^{-1}(V)$ not open, that is, there exists $x\in f^{-1}(V)$ (thus $f(x)\in V$) such that $B(x,\frac1n))\not\subseteq f^{-1}(V)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ consider $x_n\in B(x,\frac1n)\setminus f^{-1}(V)$. One can prove that $x_n\to x$. If $f(x_n)\to f(x)$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x_n)\in V$ for $n>N$, which implies $f^{-1}f(x_n)\subseteq f^{-1}(V)$ for $n>N$, a contradiction since $x_n\in f^{-1}f(x_n)$ and $x_n\notin f^{-1}(V)$.

Comment: We are given that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. My question is about the converse that assumes that $X$ is metrizable. I want to know if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open. Munkres proves this indirectly by showing $f(\bar{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}, A \subseteq X$. I want to prove this directly.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited my answer. Hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you a lot rldias! I think I realize the flaw I made in the proof that I did not type up. I will try to analyze this later on.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take open $V$ and assume $f^{-1}(V)$ is not open. That means that there exists $x\in f^{-1}(V)$ such that for all $n$, $B_n:=B(x,1/n)\not\subseteq f^{-1}(V)$, i.e. for all $n$, there exists $x_n\in B_n$ and $x_n\not\in f^{-1}(V)$. Yet, $x_n\to x$. Arrive at contradiction from here.

Comment: Why do we have that $x_n \notin f^{-1}(V)$? Why can we not have that $x, x_n \in f^{-1}(V)$ (for some $n$ or for all $n$ after some index), but the whole of $B_n$ isn't necessarily contained in $f^{-1}(V)$? This was my main difficulty (in the proof I did not type up). I knew neighborhoods of $x$ have all $x_n$'s after some index and $f^{-1}(V)$ too has all $x_n$'s after some index (I forgot if this is the same index), but I really could not conclude $f^{-1}(V)$ is open from sharing this same property as every neighborhood of $f^{-1}(V)$. I could also not conclude that some neighborhood

Comment: should be completely contained in $f^{-1}(V)$.

Comment: @Jack Bauer, you have $x_n\not\in f^{-1}(V)$ because *you choose to*. You could just as well choose $x_n = x$, so you'd have $x_n\in f^{-1}(V)$. But that wouldn't lead anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sequence lemma (as Munkres formulates it):

> If $A \subseteq X$ and $x_n$ is a sequence from $A$ with $x_n \to x$, then $x \in \overline{A}$ and the reverse holds in metrisable spaces.

Then suppose $f: X \to Y$ is sequentially continuous and $X$ is metrisable then $f$ is continuous. We can also show continuity by showing $f^{-1}[C]$ to be closed for $C \subseteq Y$ closed. So let $C$ be closed and let $x \in \overline{f^{-1}[C]}$. By the sequence lemma (reverse) there is a sequence $x_n$ from $f^{-1}[C]$ that converges to $x$. 
So $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ by sequential continuity. Also, all $f(x_n) \in C$. As $C$ is closed by the sequence lemma again $f(x) \in \overline{C}=C$, so $x \in f^{-1}[C]$. As $x \in \overline{f^{-1}[C]}$ was arbitrary, $f^{-1}[C]$ is closed. Hence $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I want to use the original definition of continuity. You're using another equivalent formulation, but it is much closer to the original definition compared to the one Munkres is using. Thank you!